# Displaying php table with postdate first

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Have a piece of code which displays video posts within an admin panel, for some reason its not displaying any new data. So im wondering if there is a way to display these post with the latest at the top and sorted by date so all new ones will show

```
 if(!empty($post['images'])){
 $images = unserialize($post['images']);
 }else{
 $images = array('no_image.jpg');
 }
 $content.= "<tr>"
 . "<td>{$post['title']}</td>"
 . "<td><img src='" . base_url(ltrim($images[0], "./")) ."' widht='25' height='25' /></td>"
 . "<td>" . substr(strip_tags($post['content']), 0, 10) . "</td>"
 . "<td>"
 . "<a href='". site_url('admin/video/edit') . "/" . $post['id'] ."'>Edit</a> | "
 . "<a href='". site_url('admin/video/delete') . "/" . $post['id'] ."'>Delete</a>"
 . "</td>"
 . "</tr>";
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong in this code (at least as it looks). The variable $post['images'] is not getting the latest ones. Please check from where this $post['images'] variable is populated.

Answer (score 2):

You missed $_POST PHP global variable.

Try this:

```
  if(!empty($_POST['images'])){
      $images = unserialize($_POST['images']);
  }else{
      $images = array('no_image.jpg');
  }
  $content.= "<tr>"
  . "<td>{$post['title']}</td>"
  . "<td><img src='" . base_url(ltrim($images[0], "./")) ."' widht='25' height='25'/></td>"
  . "<td>" . substr(strip_tags($_POST['content']), 0, 10) . "</td>"
  . "<td>"
  . "<a href='". site_url('admin/video/edit') . "/" . $_POST['id'] ."'>Edit</a> | "
  . "<a href='". site_url('admin/video/delete') . "/" . $_POST['id'] ."'>Delete</a>"
  . "</td>"
  . "</tr>";
```

this will help.

Comment: Thanks guys ill give it whirl later on when i get home! and let you no the results!!!